# Move Firefox user settings to another folder on same machine

Tags: firefox, firefox-profile, roaming-profiles

Due to company restrictions where I currently work, My windows users folder `%USERPROFILE%` is space restricted.

I get a warning that I must delete files before I can log off.

Because of that, I have moved everything else out of my profile folder (maven repository, IntelliJ configuration & cache).

I need to tell Firefox to put userprofiles somewhere else on my machine (like for instance `C:\ff_profiles\` ). How do I do that?

## Update

Thanks to answer by harrymc, i found the information on how to tweak the file `profiles.ini`. Here are the exact steps I used:

Go to folder `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox`

Move your profile data folder (randomly named: 0uq81z89.default) to c:\firefox_profiles\

Edit `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini` to point at new location:

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=0
Path=C:\bin\firefox_profiles\0uq81z89.default
```

This works like a charm. Thanks everybody for contributing with answers

Comment: Note that if you want to play with profiles, a relative path needs to use `/` whilst a full path needs to use `\` in the path addresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this mozillaZine article : [Moving your profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_FAQs_:_Changing_Profile_Folder_Location).

It describes several ways of achieving your goal:

- Using the Profile Manager to move your profile
- Create a new profile and copy the old one over it
- Create a new profile and migrate your old data
- Modify profiles.ini to point to the new location (Advanced)

Comment: +1, Just remember that the profile is now locked down to the physical machine where you moved it. If your USERPROFILE can get mapped to another machine, you will miss your firefox profile there.

Comment: @nik: Good point to pay attention to, but OK for me that profile is locked to machine.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to answer by harrymc, i found the information on how to tweak the file `profiles.ini`. Here are the exact steps I used:

Go to folder `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox`

Move your profile data folder (randomly named: 0uq81z89.default) to c:\firefox_profiles\

Edit `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles.ini` to point at new location:

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=0
Path=C:\bin\firefox_profiles\0uq81z89.default
```

This works like a charm. Thanks everybody for contributing with answers

Comment: Its a good idea to update with your data. But, it would be more appropriate as an edit in your question with a new section under the existing text. And, you could also accept harrymc's answer if it seems to have solved your question.

Comment: @nik, good point, I updated question with details

Answer (score 1):

Like I commented under `harrymc`'s answer, if you find that you want to use the profile in other places, you can also backup a compressed profile without the 'Cache' data in your `%USERPROFILE%` area.

The general steps would be

- Compress the profile (the one that you moved earlier to `C:\`)
- Leave out the `Cache` directory contents while compressing -- that will keep it light
- Keep the compressed archive safely some place in your `%USERPROFILE%` area

You can script this backup (tips in a different discussion [here](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-speed-up-firefox-significantly-with-tmpfs/)).
You can keep another script to open your profile in any other place.
Remember to backup and delete the profile from any other machines where you open it.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few options for doing this, it's a pretty easy process. You could use an add-on like [FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/febe/) to backup and restore or you can do thin manually. Take a look here;

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Profiles

Comment: Super User doesn't use BBCode, it uses Markdown.