# How can I prevent Firefox from storing a 10 MB places database file in my Windows roaming profile?

Tags: windows, firefox, roaming-profiles

On my work PC, Firefox stores a 10 MB file called `places.sqlite` in my roaming profile:

```
C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\PROFILE_ID\places.sqlite
```

I don't use any location-related features in Firefox, and this file causes my roaming profile to be larger than my company allows (25 MB), meaning I get warnings about my profile size every day.

Can I stop Firefox storing this file in my roaming profile?

Comment: This approach could help, although it does appear to destroy the entire roaming profile: http://superuser.com/questions/138275/move-firefox-user-settings-to-another-folder-on-same-machine

Comment: For the record, 25MB is an absurdly small limit for a roaming profile.  Firefox is likely to be only the first of your problems.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Although I concur with your real life observation, I must debate that the user profile size on a common Windows system is absurd. Nowadays application developers tend to depreciate the importance of small storage foot print, they also tend to confuse cache data with user persistence and with user independent data. To my opinion, the least an application should do is to give the option to separate those locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`places.sqlite` is not about location information, it's about Firefox history and bookmarks.
See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite:

> The file "places.sqlite" stores the annotations, bookmarks, favorite icons, input history, keywords, and browsing history (a record of visited pages).

There is no simple way to move only your `places.sqlite` to another location. The following [bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=385077) is about setting the `places.sqlite` location and it is resolved as WONTFIX. Maybe you can get some useful information from that bug's comments.

You can try taking the whole Firefox profile out of your roaming profile location. See [Changing Firefox profile folder location](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Thunderbird_:_FAQs_:_Changing_Profile_Folder_Location). 
Though, this will take out the point from a roaming profile, right? ;)

You can also tell Firefox not to save your browsing history, this can decrease the places file size. Or, Firefox also have an option to delete your history upon closing the browser, this will still let you have history of the current session. (Update: see first comment by Paul D. Waite about this option)

Comment: "You can also tell Firefox not to save your browsing history, this can decrease the places file size." - I don't think this will decrease it below 10 MB. I gave it a go, and places.sqlite stayed at 10 MB. I believe the file is stored in 10 MB chunks (see http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2129111&start=30). Great answer though, much appreciated.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You could try storing the actual file in a different location and use a symbolic link within the FF profile. Of course, if you're actually roaming this might not work too well.

Comment: @Bob Using links for this task, one should be careful from concurrent file access by different instances. This solution is discussed in comments on the bug report I've linked to, search for the word `link` on the bug page for more details. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=385077